# How to enforce code analysis check in policy in VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I'm looking at here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/add-check-policies?view=vsts

It says to go to Source Control under Project, but there is no Project section, no Source Control anywhere either.

[image: ss from VS]

I thought I would be able to enforce Code Analysis from Azure DevOps dashboard, can't find where the settings is neither.

I am the Project Admin, I do have "Edit project-level information" allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seems you are using Git as version control, however the check in policy is against TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control).

For Git you can set the branch policies, please see [Improve code quality with branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=vsts) for details.

As far as I know, there isn't the equal way to enable Code Analysis policy for Git. However, you can use the extension [Code Analysis](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TotalALM.totalalm-codeanalysis) or [SonarQube](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube) to run the Code Analysis in build/release pipeline...

If you insist on using the check in policy, then you can create a project which select TFVC as the Version Control tool...

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to enforce Code Analysis policy if I'm using Git? Changing to TFVC is not an option.

Comment: @Farid As far as I know, there isn't the equal way to enable Code Analysis policy for Git. However, you can use the extension [Code Analysis](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TotalALM.totalalm-codeanalysis) or [SonarQube](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube) to run the Code Analysis in build/release pipeline...